# Как преобразовать дату в формат ДД месяца ГГ

Tags: javascript

Как преобразовать дату из формата:

```
06Mar2018 
21Sep2017
```

и т.д., в формат:

```
6 марта 2018
27 сентября 2017
```

Answer (score 7):

```
var options = {  
     day: "numeric", month: "long",  year: "numeric"   
};
var myDate = new Date("06Mar2018");  
document.write(myDate.toLocaleDateString("ru-RU", options));
```

Comment: Чтобы работало и в Firefox: `new Date("06Mar2018".replace(/^(\d{1,2})([a-z]{3})(\d{2,4})$/i,'$1 $2 $3'));`